# Delete lines from a text file that match multiple regexes on a text file

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

Let's say I have **FileA.txt** which looks a bit like this:

```
43287134, string1, string2
1233, foo, bar
973, barfoo, foobar
7464, asdf, ghjk
```

And I've got **FileB.txt** with these regexes, separated by a line:

```
^973,
^1233,
```

I would like to apply **FileB.txt** regexes onto **FileA.txt**, and delete the lines that match so that final result would be:

```
43287134, string1, string2
7464, asdf, ghjk
```

Is there any tool available to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to delete only lines that match *any* the regexes in the file.  This is a different problem from deleting or keeping lines that match 2 or more regexes from a large set of patterns.  (i.e. where a single line has to match multiple regexes).  Your title is confusing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is exactly what `grep` is designed for:

```
grep -v -f FileB.txt FileA.txt
```

- `-f <filename>` reads regexes from the file (instead of command line)
- `-v` reverse the match (prints non-matching lines)

Output:

```
43287134, string1, string2
7464, asdf, ghjk
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done with `sed`:

```
while read -r REG_EX; do sed -i "/$REG_EX/d" FileA.txt; done<FileB.txt
```

Comment: won't work due to first ^ character in fileB.txt  -bash-4.4$ while read -r REG_EX; do sed -i "/$REG_EX/d" toto ; done < titi
-bash-4.4$ 
as you see no output  :) to avoid that you can try sed without -i but you will get as number of outputs as number of line from fileB like that :  -bash-4.4$ while read -r REG_EX; do sed  "/$REG_EX/d" toto ; done < titi
43287134, string1, string2                  
7464, asdf, ghjk  
43287134, string1, string2                  
7464, asdf, ghjk  
-bash-4.4$

Comment: @francoisP: What OS are you running? On my mac I have to use `sed -i.bak...` but it does work.  Also there should be no output.  It doesn't produce output with `-i` it just modifies the file.

Comment: tryied on both linux and BSD  it's similar/same

Comment: @francoisP: Have you checked your `toto` file to see if it's been modified?  As I said above this command should not produce any output to STDOUT.

Comment: I always test in real before posting . of course with -i it is ok to get no output but infile result is same double  results ...

Comment: Alright well I have learned exactly nothing.  Does that mean it works or not?